# How to print the Addthis block code into a template

Tags: 7

I've installed the [AddThis](https://www.drupal.org/project/addthis) module and am trying to print the buttons on my template, however I can't get it to work. Here's the I'm using:

```
$addblock = module_invoke('addthis','block_view','addthis_block');
print render($addblock['content']);
```

For the record, If I switch to Bootstrap theme, the links are displayed on the page, if I switch to my own theme (Bootstrap child-theme) it doesn't. I've copied the code verbatim from `modules/node/node.tpl.php` and it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to do it in a classic way? Why don't you print region in your theme, and put that block in it using blocks configuration GUI? You know, the way it was designed to work?

Comment: And how is the classic way? Using the module?

Comment: Classic way is to print region in theme, and then go to admin->blocks and assign that block to a region.

Comment: Ah, ok I got you mean, in this it wouldn't work for me as I'd like to have more control over the location of the buttons than this approach would allow me. Unless I create a specific region for each content type (which I'd rather not do).

Comment: But you can have one region and only output it differently per content type.

Comment: yes, but the different would be in different location on the page depending on the content type. Some pages would be at the bottom, some at the top and some in the middle. That's why I was trying to use something that would allow me a bit more control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you enable the **Display Setting** in your **addthis** block configuration because code is good go it working for me, so go and configure the display setting surely it will work.. its under **admin/structure/block/manage/addthis/addthis_block/configure** enable it as you need by "Basic button or Basic Toolbar"...